# C++/multiple files with vector of object pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, file, object, vector

The basic idea of this problem should make sense by looking at the code below but I'll try to explain. Basically I have two classes which reference each other via pointers and then these classes are in two separate header files. The program only works without the part where a vector of type b pointers is added into A.h.

```
#include <iostream>  
#include "A.h"  
#include "B.h"  

using namespace std;  
class a;  
class b;  

int main()  
{  
    a* oba = new a;  
    b* obb = new b;  

    oba->set(obb,9);  
    obb->set(oba,0);  


    cout<<oba->get()<<endl;  
    cout<<obb->get()<<endl;  
    delete obb;  
    delete oba;  

    return 0;  
}  

//This is the A.h, look for the comment in the code where the error occurred.

#ifndef _A  
#define _A  

#include "B.h"  
#include <vector>  

class b;  

class a  
{  
    private:  
        b* objb;  
        int data;  
        vector <b*> vecb;//this is not well liked by the compiler???  

    public:  

    void set(b* temp, int value);  
    int get();  
};  
void a::set(b* temp, int value)  
{  
    objb = temp;  
    data = value;  
}  
int a::get()  
{  
    return data;  
}  
#endif  



#ifndef _B  
#define _B  

#include "A.h"  
class a;  

class b  
{  
    private:  
        a* obja;  
        int data;  

    public:  
    void set(a* temp, int value);  
    int get();   
};  
void b::set(a* temp, int value)  
{    
    obja = temp;  
    data = value;  
}  
int b::get()    
{  
    return data;   
}  
#endif
```

Comment: And what is the error the compiler gives you?

Comment: Hi, I just split this into 3 files and build it on VS2010 with no problems. Can you please tell us what the actual error is and what compiler you're using? Thanks.

Comment: Nevermind. I was using codeblocks I guess its g++ but I added 'using namespace std' into A.h and it worked.

Comment: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of `vector' with no type

Comment: So I added std::vector <b*> vecb; and it worked? Is that ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qualify vector with std namespace.

```
class a
{
    ...
    std::vector<b*> vecb;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't `#include "A.h"` in your `B.h`, and vice versa, otherwise you get circular dependencies.

Try the following:

(A.h)

```
class B; // forward declaration
class A
{
    B* pb;
    ...
}
```

(A.cpp)

```
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"
...
```

(B.h)

```
class A; // forward declaration
class B
{
    A* pa;
    ...
}
```

(B.cpp)

```
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"
...
```

HTH.

Comment: Please see my code below. I got this error again with this.                   error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of `vector' with no type|

Answer (score 0):

I added `std::vector <b*> vecb;`  to the code first posted and it compiled fine.